# how to create a pdf upload file or drag and drop file modal component in angular 11,14,15

Tags: angular, pdf, file-upload, drag-and-drop, angular15

Please find below the design for the desktop and mobile view

[desktop view of pdf file upload design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7hSi.png)
[mobile view of pdf file upload design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzUpM.png)

Comment: What have you tried? Typing "angular drag drop file upload" into a search engine returns quite a few examples which should help you to get started. If you still can't get it working then you can ask a question here, showing us the code you've written and explaining in exactly what way it isn't working (e.g. compilation error, runtime error, different behaviour between different platforms). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. As it stands, your question is not specific enough to be answered.